# recv()/read() in client never terminates

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to implement a client that receives and sends data from/to a server. However, while the sending works, the receive never does and my program just hangs there.

This is my bare bones problem area without any error checking.

```
    //send data
    char* message = "LIST\n";
    write(sockfd, message, 5);

    //receive data
    int numbytes;
    char buf[100];
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 99, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1); 
    }
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';
```

I even tried something insanely basic-

```
//send data
char* message = "LIST\n";
write(sockfd, message, 5);

//receive data
char* buf = calloc(1, 100);
read(sockfd, buf, 7);        //the message I'm supposed to receive is 7 bytes, but I even tried 6 and 8 to account for any nulls etc
```

This hangs at read too.

EDIT: It terminates after I added

```
shutdown(sockfd, 1);
```

after the send data part, however while the response should be

```
OK\n7
try.txt
```

The only response I get is

```
OK
```

Comment: I'm not experienced in C network programming, but are both ends running the same code? If so, it looks synchronous and like both sides are trying to send their data, which may involve waiting for the other end to receive it (which would cause it to hang). I could be entirely wrong, but I hope to get you on the right track at least. Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here are some links to the [help] and the [tour] for you to check out if you need.

Comment: More importantly, post a [mcve]

Comment: *Send* and *receives* should be symmetric (in order and message type/size). When you `send` in a process, other process should `receive`. Here you are not following that logic. In your code, both are sending and then both are receiving.

Comment: @Delioth Ah thanks! I used 'shutdown()' to terminate the write end of the socket, and now it doesn't hang, though it still doesn't print everything it's supposed to.

Comment: @Arash I'm sending a request to a server (as a client) and I'm trying to save the response from the server into a buffer. So, I have to both send and receive.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I don't know how to post a complete example, because I don't have the code for the reference server anyway. I only have the executable.

Comment: @Kek ...  if that means that you don't know the server protocol in use, then you have a stupendous problem.

Comment: @Kek --  What I am saying is: it should be like this----> client: `send(sockfd, x,..); recv(sockfd, y, ...);` server: `recv(sockfd, x,...); send(sockfd, y,...);`

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I do, it's described in the problem documentation.

Comment: Please add more code here: how you create the socket, TCP or UDP, binding, etc. Otherwise it's impossible to understand the problem you have.